# How to find the range of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

This problem is taken from Rudin   analysis , Chapter 9 page No : $242$ . Problem No.$24$

> For  $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ , define  $f = (f_1 , f_2)$ by $f_1 (x,y) = \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ ,$f_2 = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$
>
> Compute the rank  of $ f'(x,y)$  and find  the range  of $f$

My attempt : i found the  answer and my doubt  is in red line  and red circle

[image]

im not getting the red line  and red circle ?

I need help !

Comment: Don't you put these into the formulae for $f_1$ and $f_2$ and the right thing comes out?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown if i put $u= 1$  , then $v$ will be$ 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused with the following terminology:

> The point $y$ is the image of $x$.

This really just means that $x$ is taken to $y$ under the function $f$ under discussion; in other words $f(x)=y$. In your case, "$(1,0)$ is its own image" means nothing but $f(1,0)=(1,0)$ which you can check easily:
$$f(1,0)=(f_1(1,0),f_2(1,0))=\left(\frac{1^2-0^2}{1^2+0^2},\frac{1\cdot0}{1^2+0^2}\right)=(1,0).$$
The statement for $(-1,0)$ is the same thing. The part in the red circle just says that
$$\begin{split}f\left(1,\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}\right)&=\left(\frac{1^2-(1-u)/(1+u)}{1^2+(1-u)/(1+u)},\frac{\pm\sqrt{(1-u)/(1+u)}}{1^2+(1-u)/(1+u)}\right)\\ &=\left(u,\pm\frac12\sqrt{(1-u)(1+u)}\right)\end{split}$$
where the second coordinate of the RHS is the same as $v$ in the line immediately above the red circle.